# Android detect sdk suspicious behivior

Tags: android, malware-detection

My android app uses diffrent sdks which are used as 'black box'.
I want to detect suspicious behivior in these sdks, for example if they are using internet connection and which url they connect to.
is there a programmatically way to detect if the sdks that are deployed in my app are using the internet connection and to which url they are connecting ?